# Can we load the terms and conditions as a PDF in a UIWebview for IOS apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding terms and conditions to my app in a UIWebview. What i really want to know is can i show it as a page by page pdf document or should i use any other method? Will App store accept the pdf format?

Comment: All the Answers below are perfect and working. Since i can select only one answer i am selecting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using `UIWebview` and surely **will get accepted by Apple**.

If you are trying to display a PDF file from a web URL , use the below code.

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/file_toopen.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Or if you have a PDF file bundled with in your application, use below code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filetoopen" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Thanks that is helpful

Answer (score 2):

**Apple Surely approve** , in here you can implement in two ways

1. **UIWebview**

   ```
   NSString *pathofFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"pdf"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathofFile]];
   [webView loadRequest:request];
   ```
2. **UIDocumentInteractionController** preferable for PDF

   ```
   NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"pdf"];

   if (URL) {
   // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
   self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

   // Configure Document Interaction Controller
   [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

   // Preview PDF
   [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
   }
   ```

Sample [Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130)

Comment: if you need any additional help for this

Comment: Thanks this is very much helpful